# How to read data from excel using with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to import data from excel sheet(.xlsx). I have found [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) for import data but after downloading document and source code I am confused which file is important for me. I also tried to find out document on that site but not found the way.

**About my task:** Read excel sheet data from selected sheet and insert data to my database table.

So I really thankful If You will guide me how to use it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the PHPExcel library to read an Excel file and insert the data into a database.

Sample code is below.

```
//  Include PHPExcel_IOFactory
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = 'sample.xls';

//  Read your Excel workbook
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                    NULL,
                                    TRUE,
                                    FALSE);
    //  Insert row data array into database here using your own structure
```

Comment: A better answer than transferring the entire worksheet to a PHP array; iterate over each row in turn so you're only working with a small array of data and you're not going to blow PHP's memory limit

Comment: In case you know the format of the data before hand, e.g. a user upload, you can set `$highestColumn` to the last column of data such as `$highestColumn = 'E'` in my own case. This is useful as your database will generally have fixed columns.

Answer (score 8):

From a quick look over the documentation, use the IOFactory to automatically determine the file format.

```
include 'path/to/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

// Let IOFactory determine the spreadsheet format
$document = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('path/to/spreadsheet.xls');

// Get the active sheet as an array
$activeSheetData = $document->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

var_dump($activeSheetData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this so you can jump start the development process:

```
include '.... /PHPexcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    $dataFfile = "C:/tmp/test_data.xls";
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($dataFfile);
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $data = $sheet->rangeToArray('A2:AB5523');
    echo "Rows available: " . count($data) . "\n";
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
```

Replace the include path with your path to the PHPExcel.php
Replace `$dataFile` with your excel file
Also adjust the range of the cells that you want to import